# How to duplicate an eks cluster with eksctl or cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, eksctl

I have an eks cluster that is being deployed with terraform and have been tasked with creating an eksctl or cloudformation alternative. I have a version of the eks cluster I need to duplicate up and running.

Is there a command I can point to an existing cluster to get the yaml or json I need to duplicate the cluster with an aws native cli command?

[Heres an example of eksctl yaml](https://github.com/RajitPaul11/AmazonEKS/blob/master/EKS-Managed-NodeGroups-Cluster/cluster.yaml), I basically need to generate a similar file based on an existing cluster, when I dont know all the configuration details ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [Former2](https://former2.com/) to generate the CloudFormation template from your EKS cluster.